# No a2dp_source in Pulseaudio for bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have a pair of Jabra Active Elite 75t earbuds.

When I connect them via bluetooth, in the A2DP profile they are added as a sink, but not as a source. As source they are only available in the HSP/HFP profile, which has poor sound quality.

How can I configure Pulseaudio to add the microphone input also in the A2DP profile?

Output from `pactl list cards`

```
Card #1
    Name: bluez_card.70_BF_92_D0_E0_B1
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: 24
    Properties:
        device.description = "Jabra Elite Active 75t"
        device.string = "70:BF:92:D0:E0:B1"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_70_BF_92_D0_E0_B1"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "Jabra Elite Active 75t"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Profiles:
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 30, available: yes)
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 40, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: a2dp_sink
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit, a2dp_sink
        headset-input: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit
```

`bluetoothd` logs:

```
Jun 02 17:37:51 mptop4 bluetoothd[13144]: Starting SDP server
Jun 02 17:37:51 mptop4 bluetoothd[13144]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jun 02 17:37:51 mptop4 bluetoothd[13144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.148 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jun 02 17:37:51 mptop4 bluetoothd[13144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.148 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jun 02 17:38:31 mptop4 bluetoothd[13144]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_70_BF_92_D0_E0_B1/sep1/fd0: fd(51) ready
```

Comment: A2DP is stereo *without* microphone, there's no way around it. What you want can't be done.

Comment: I would have to have the headset show up as 2 devices then, one as sink and the other as source?

Comment: No. Your options are A2DP (stereo, no mic) or HFP (mono + mic).

Comment: My headphone shows up with a2dp_source but it seems I can't switch to it: 

 profiles:
  a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: unknown)
  a2dp_source: High Fidelity Capture (A2DP Source) (priority 20, available: no)
  headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: unknown)
  off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)

Switching to it leads to this error:

``pacmd set-card-profile bluez_card.address_to_my_headphone a2dp_source
Failed to set card profile to 'a2dp_source'.``